# Why doesn't this equality check work in Ajax success callback?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this jQuery code :

```
success: function(vote_msg){
    alert(vote_msg);
    if(vote_msg == 'ok')  {
         alert("something");
    } else {
    }
};
```

It alerts **ok**, but not **something**, what could the problem be?

Comment: This isn't a casing issue?

Comment: Try `if( $.trim(vote_msg) == 'ok')  { ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vote_msg` is likely *not* what is expected. I suspect there is extra whitespace and/or a newline.

To see this, here are some suggestions:

1. Use edge guards - quick n' dirty, but this will NOT show some extra tricky cases:

   `alert(">" + vote_msg + "<")`
2. Stringify/encode per JSON rules. Characters like \n (and zero-sized space!) will be encoded and the surrounding quotes will reveal spaces at each end:

   `alert(JSON.stringify({msg: vote_msg}))`
3. Use a debugger and inspect the data. This offers the most control and "live" access:

   `debugger`
4. Inspect the *actual* network response (e.g. Firebug or Developer Tools).

After identifying the problem using one (or more) of the above, fix it :) The correct solution likely involves updating the server code, if possible. I recommend *returning JSON* (generated automatically!) for consistency and extensibility.

Comment: it gives this  : >"a square"ok< I use this on php : `echo 'ok';` I don't see what the problem is.

Comment: "a square" as in a rectangular shape, or the actual string ?

Comment: you know the square you get when a browser tries to show a Chinese character or something like that

Comment: Usually caused by encoding errors, file not saved as UTF8 etc. Guessing it looks a lot like �

Comment: @adeneo Good catch, confused you with the OP for second!

Answer (score 0):

Is this just a mistake in posting or did you forget to put a semicolon after alert(vote_msg)?

Comment: A semi-colon is automatically inserted per ASI rules - manually adding one does not change the grammar productions.